# Create array of property values from list based on condition

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, list

I've recently used this site to get the code to extract an array of property values from a list of objects (I've searched again and again and can't find the original post or help on the update :()

This is the result:

```
qtyArray.AddRange(plan.Components.Select(c => c.qty.HasValue ? (int)c.qty.Value : 0).ToArray());
```

Problem is, I have other properties i'm outputting into parallel arrays to pass to a datasource but would prefer to ignore any false 'active' properties.  So for all the arrays do something like above, but only where c.active == true:

```
plan.Components.Select(c => c.qty.HasValue ? (int)c.qty.Value : 0 **WHERE c.active**)
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this:

```
plan.Components.Where(c => c.active).Select (c => c.qty.HasValue ? (int)c.qty.Value : 0 )
```

It should do the required filtering.

Comment: That looks like the one, i'm sure there's a few more ways but this requires hardly any refactoring. A+.

Answer (score 0):

```
plan.Components.Select(c => c.qty.HasValue ? (int)c.qty.Value : 0 && (c.active == null ? false : c.active));
```

Take note though that it will assume that if active is null then active is false